# P(x<1) and E(x) of a Rayleigh Distribution

Tags: probability

I just wanted to verify my answer to a very simple question involving the Rayleigh distribution.  It's one of those "shotgun aimed at bullseye" questions, and we are given the CDF of the distance X from the bullseye (It's a Rayleigh distribution with sigma=1).  The CDF is 1-exp(-x^2/2)

We are asked for P(X<1) and E(X); I believe that the Rayleigh distribution with sigma=1 can be approximated by chi-square distribution with 2 degrees of freedom.

Then, the problem becomes finding E(x) and P(x<1) for a chi-square with 2 degrees of freedom (E(x)=2,  P(x<1)=0.3934693).  Is my logic appropriate for this problem?

Thanks for your help!

Sarah

Comment: You should find $P(X<1)$ and $E(X)$ from Rayleigh distribution. By substituting 'x' with '1' in CDF, you get the probability. By taking derivative of CDF and use usual definition of $E(x)$ as $E(x)=\int_0^\infty xf(x)dx$ you can find its expectation.

Answer (score 0):

No, your calculations are incorrect. A Rayleigh random variable is the **square root** of a $\chi_2^2$ random variable, and so you cannot find its mean etc the way you have done it. The expectation of a
$\chi_2^2$ random variable is indeed $2$, but that is not the
expected value of its square root.

Consider that *by definition*, the value of the CDF at any point $\alpha$ equals $P\{X \leq \alpha\}$.  Do you know the CDF $F_X(x)$ of your Rayleigh
random variable? Can you use this knowledge to evaluate $P\{X \leq 1\}$?
What about $P\{X < 1\}$?

For finding $E[X]$, I will suggest that you use a wonderful formula
that applies to random variables taking on only nonnegative values:

$$E[X] = \int_0^\infty P\{X > x\}\,\mathrm dx
= \int_0^\infty [1-F_X(x)]\,\mathrm dx$$
where you are warned to *not* apply PEMDAS to open those square
brackets in the second integral and break it up into the difference
of two integrals.  Do you know a formula for $[1-F_X(x)]$?
Can you figure out the value of
$\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2/2}\,\mathrm dx$ **by inspection** and what you
know already, that is, without actually having to integrate,
or attempt to integrate and then saying that you don't know how
to calculate the integral?  No? How about
$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2/2}\,\mathrm dx$?  Can you figure
out the value of that? No? How about
$\sqrt{2\pi}\left[ \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-x^2/2}\,\mathrm dx\right]$? Do you know the value of the integral in 
square brackets?

Comment: Thank you for the clarification that the Rayleigh distribution is the square root of chi-square(df=2)... Got it!